# Get param from parent component to child component

Tags: angular, angular-router

There have been so many alterations to the Angular router as of late I don't know how to go about this.

I have a param on my parent component called "eventId" which is in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:4200/event/1
```

In this case it's value is 1.

Here's how I declare it in the routing component:

```
{ path: 'event/:eventId', loadChildren: './event/event.module#EventModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

So I have a child component which is way down the line:

```
http://localhost:4200/event/1/event-travel-agents/purchase-plans
```

On my purchase plans component, how can I get the eventId?

I've tried:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
export class PurchasePlansComponent implements OnInit {
  eventId: number;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.subscription = activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe(
      (param: any) => {
        this.eventId = param['eventId'];
      }
    );
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    alert(this.eventId);
  }
}
```

But this only works if I'm at this level:

```
http://localhost:4200/event/1/event-home
```

But if I'm at this level it won't work:

```
http://localhost:4200/event/1/event-travel-agents/purchase-plans
```

Comment: (not able to test at the moment but just to give you an idea) have you tried something like: `activatedRoute.snapshot.parent.params['eventId']` ?

Comment: what is the error if any i feel it should work as you are dealing with the same component , if not go for [shared services](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) but i feel it should work.

Comment: @deezg using snapshot wont work for scenarios where the param changes dynamically you need to subscribe to the changes

Comment: @RahulSingh why wouldn't it work? i don't see anything that would suggest his components get reused. or am i missing something?

Comment: @deezg he is looking to get the event id for that particular param just i guess and the event id will just change

Comment: @RahulSingh yes, he tries to get `eventId` and that's why his subscription fires only on top level, but on levels below `eventId` is constant and thus nothing to fire. that's why i think he might want to go with `snapshot.parent`. at least that's what i would try first.

Comment: Sorry I get:
vendor.bundle.js:118866 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: activatedRoute.snapshot.parent.params.subscribe is not a function
TypeError: activatedRoute.snapshot.parent.params.subscribe is not a function

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 5.2 release there is new feature of **paramsInheritanceStrategy** ,that can help you for your problems now.

You can use it as following

```
@NgModule({
    import :[RouterModule.forRoot(router,{paramsInheritanceStrategy :'always'})]
})
```

It defines how the router merges params, data and resolved data from parent to child

**Available options are:**

**1.** **emptyOnly:** **the default** , only inherits parent params for path-less or component-less

**2.** **always:** enables unconditional inheritance of parent params.

In component you can use it as follows:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.eventId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("eventId");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.
The answer was very lengthy. Without subscription the line was:

```
this.eventId = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.parent.params.eventId;
```