# How to fetch route parameters from current and parent routes and fetch data from Redux store?

Tags: angular, redux, observable

I am building an app with Angular 6 and Redux.

In many components when I need to fetch a data from Redux store I am using the well documented pattern (https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) to fetching the route parameter from the route.
So, in a simple case the component may look like this:

```
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  activeProject$: Observable<ActiveProject>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private projectActions: ProjectActions,
              private store: NgRedux<AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activeProject$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        const id = +params.get('id');

        this.projectActions.loadProjectById(id);

        return this.store.select<ActiveProject>(['projectList', 'map', id]);
      })
    );
  }

}
```

This one a pretty clear, and works perfectly.
Now, I have a child component to the one above and the route to of that component is something like this:

```
...
{
  path: 'project/:id',  component: ProjectComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'tool/:toolId',  component: ProjectToolComponent }
  ]
}
...
```

So, in `ProjectToolComponent` I need to get both parameters and get both objects from the store: `Project` & `ProjectTool`.

What is the easiest way to do it?
The main issue, is that I need project ID in order to get the tool object.

What I've tried doing is (inside my ProjectToolComponent):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tool$ = this.route.parent.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((parentParams: ParamMap) => {
        this.projectId = +parentParams.get('id');

        return this.route.paramMap.pipe(
          switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
            this.utilizationId = +params.get('utilizationId');

            this.projectToolUtilizationActions.loadProjectTools(this.projectId);

            return this.store.select<ToolUtilization>(['projectToolsMap', this.projectId]).pipe(
              find(tool => tool.id === this.utilizationId)
            );
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

But, it does not seem to work.
I could not find any docs related to this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get param from parent component to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935269/get-param-from-parent-component-to-child-component)

Comment: The described approach using the `paramsInheritance` feature should simplify your issue at least